# How to send data to GSM/GPRS modem(e.g. sim800,sim900,quectel m66) from http server

Tags: http, server, gsm, at-command, gprs

I want to send data to GSM module from http server,what are the ways to receive any data send from http server to gsm module?
My goal is to control my GSM/GPRS module from a web server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can program a esp8266 (nodeMCU) or atmega23u4/atmega328p (arduino nano) to communicate with the sim800L using SoftwareSerial. Then, you can program the http server to store the actions desired and then, periodically pull the http server *from* the sim800L to read the ops and make them (optionally to mark them as done).

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_httpmethods.asp

http://opensta.org/docs/sclref10/imp3ln43.htm#19484

It is nearly impossible to do it the other way from scratch. You would need to program an http server in nodeMCU (possible) and accepting requests at the public (usually changing, with most ports filtered) ip of the gprs module.

Comment: is it possible to do this without using arduino ?like using AT commands of module to download files from server?

Comment: Sure, you can get tcp connections to a remote port using AT commands, and you can send "GET" commands to a http server running on a public ip. I have done it before, using a nodemcu to send the commands to a sim800L, but you can send the AT commands from whatever you have.

Comment: Hey,thank you for your reply but can you explain this in detail I don't know much about it,I know how to send parameters from module to server running on public ip using URL.What type of GET commands are there to receive data from server.

Comment: @R.zeiwald I just added two links explaining how to get a tcp connection with a remote server, and what content has to be sent to the server to GET a page as a browser does.